# Sitecore content versioning issue

Tags: sitecore

This is occuring in Sitecore version 6.4.1 (rev. 110720)

Recently, I've had an issue with several users who have unintentionally created a new version of an item -  which contains "empty" fields.  This is confusing to users because they don't realize that they are seeing a different version of the item, and they think that their content is randomly disappearing.

I don't know how to reproduce this, much less figure out how they are creating these "phantom" item versions.

I am reasonably certain that Sitecore users are not explicitly clicking "add" a new version in the top menu.  From what I've been told, all they are doing is "locking" the item for editing, and this seems to create the new version of the item.  At this point, it appears that the new version is the "default" that they are seeing, and they are complaining that the content has been "lost."

Is this Sitecore's default behavior - to create a new version of the item when the item is "locked" for editing?  Or is this a known issue in this version of Sitecore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an item belongs to a workflow then when you hit the "Edit" button it will create a new version automatically for you.

Also, something to look into, in previous versions of Sitecore there were numerous issues where many actions in the content editor created versions of items unexpectedly (sorting for instance). See http://seankearney.com/post/Sitecore-item-and-version-design-flaw.aspx for more information on that.

Comment: Okay, that seems to tie into what people have been telling me.  When you say "if an item belongs to a workflow" - do you mean it hasn't been approved, published or both?

Comment: No, it means there is a value in the Workflow field for the item.  Turn on standard fields, look at bottom section, "Workflow".